# validate an array of Enum in yup

Tags: typescript, yup

I need to validate an array of enums in yup.

I am using typescript so I have to utilize the exact type of the enums during validation. While using an array of strings seems to work, I want to validate the exact array of enums instead of strings. Is there a way to accomplish this?

I've added a working codesandbox as well
https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-edison-3vqp1

Here's a snippet of what I intend to do

```
import { object, array } from "yup";

enum DayEnum {
  Sunday = "Sunday",
  Monday = "Monday",
  Tuesday = "Tuesday",
  Wednesday = "Wednesday",
  Thursday = "Thursday",
  Friday = "Friday",
  Saturday = "Saturday"
}

const daysSchema = object({
  // days_of_week: array(string()),
  days_of_week: array(DayEnum)
});

const main = async () => {
  console.log(
    await daysSchema.isValid({
      days_of_week: [DayEnum.Sunday, DayEnum.Saturday]
    })
  );
};

main();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to solve this thanks to this comment: https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/1497#issue-1034140602

The solution looks like this

```
const daysSchema = object({
  days_of_week: array(
        mixed<DayEnum>().oneOf(Object.values(DayEnum)).required()
    ).ensure()
});
```